# Is this road trip from India to Singapore covering entire South-East Asia in the below mentioned route were possible?

Tags: road-trips, southeast-asia

I want to travel to this countries  mentioned below by road using car.

1. India
2. Nepal
3. Bhutan
4. Bangladesh
5. Myanmar
6. Laos
7. Vietnam
8. Cambodia
9. Thailand
10. Malaysia
11. Singapore

Yes. The Entire  **South-East Asia** mainland

Is that possible? Do they allow road trip ?

What are the legal formalities need have to be done for a successful trip ?

Comment: Welcome! We're not a travel agency, meaning you're question is not only a bit too broad, but also not really suitable. You should do some research and, when you have specific questions, come back.

Comment: The main issue with this idea is that the India/Myanmar border requires special permits to cross, and the Bangladesh/Myanmar border can't be crossed at all. See [WikiTravel.](http://wikitravel.org/en/Myanmar#By_land)

Answer (score 3):

In theory, yes it is possible to drive through those countries in that order.

I did a quick search using [Google Maps](https://www.google.no/maps/dir/India/Singapore/@13.4373112,84.6862118,5z/am=t/data=!4m49!4m48!1m40!1m1!1s0x30635ff06b92b791:0xd78c4fa1854213a6!2m2!1d78.96288!2d20.593684!3m4!1m2!1d87.275223!2d26.658505!3s0x39ef6c69349bb315:0x4bdbf9b2a14cda56!3m4!1m2!1d89.7499859!2d27.517687!3s0x39e1ea4b19babdeb:0x2b393b7a37314f03!3m4!1m2!1d90.1256731!2d27.0196496!3s0x3758afb96fe25825:0xdbd79a85f377388d!3m4!1m2!1d91.9106698!2d24.8121855!3s0x3751ac09da68ec45:0xb4e6c7a4c6d63e30!3m4!1m2!1d101.0310566!2d20.5790271!3s0x31298da1b02d4911:0x8134b5c665282372!3m4!1m2!1d105.8757957!2d21.07421!3s0x3135aa1fee42de8f:0x7ceeed49698810a1!3m4!1m2!1d106.0747173!2d13.4336788!3s0x3112eb819abae515:0xdabc3a4f82a5c646!1m5!1m1!1s0x31da1767b42b8ec9:0x400f7acaedaa420!2m2!1d103.8677444!2d1.3553794!3e0?hl=en) and that route covers all the countries on your list...

[image: Map]

It is worth noting that this trip is over 9000KM long and would take over a week of none stop driving. If you limit yourself to 6 hours driving per day then it would take approximately a month of traveling.

This is all according to Google Maps and does not consider the type or quality of the roads nor does it consider any political restrictions.

What you should do if you want to plan such a trip is to first see what Visa requirements you need to enter each country then research border crossings, there are some unfriendly borders in that region of the world so the most straight forward route might not be possible.

Comment: For Indian citizens , Nepal and Bhutan giving visa-less entry. Vehicle permit also easily obtainable if the persons are Indian citizen .

Comment: You did not state your nationality in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your nationality, you might need a visa for some of the countries in that list.

Also, countries like Nepal or Bhutan are not easily accessible by road due to their mountainous nature, especially if you are a foreigner.

Comment: For Indian citizens , Nepal and Bhutan giving visa-less entry. Vehicle permit also easily obtainable if the persons are Indian citizen .